# Compilation error when linking a C++ class (.cpp and .h) file that has a "global" function within it

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, g++, static-libraries

I'm new to everything that has to do with libraries (static and shared) in C++ and I will say in advance that the issue I'm facing is during some "educational" stuff I'm doing - so in case it does not make sense to do it (this way) in the first place, I did not know it. 
I'm working on:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

My "project" has the following files (for simplicity, all of them are located in the same folder).

- Two C++ classes from which I wish to created a static library (`classA.h` ,`classA.cpp`, `classB.h` and `classB.cpp`).
- Single "executable" file `main.cpp` that will link against the static library.

In each of the classes files (classA and classB) , I have added (in addition to a class's function) a "global" function - again, for educational purposes.

In order to created the static library and then the executable that will use it, I'm performing the following steps:

1) **Compile** the source files of the two classes into object files:
`g++ -Wall -c classA.cpp classB.cpp`

2) **Create** a static library called `myStaticLib.a` from these two object files:

`ar -cvq myStaticLib.a classA.o classB.o`

So far so good.

3) **Compiling** the `main.cpp` file  into an executable (`myExe`) linked to the static library:

`g++ -o myExe main.cpp myStaticLib.a`

--> Here I'm facing a compilation error as follows:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
>
> main.cpp:27:19: error: ‘funcFromASrcFile’ was not declared in this scope
>
> funcFromASrcFile();

In order to solve it, I added the following to lines into the `main.cpp` file:

`void funcFromASrcFile(); 
 void funcFromBSrcFile();`

Which are the signatures of the "global" functions from each .cpp file (respectively as their name states).

This solution "solves" my compilation problem and when I run the executable it works correctly.

Here are my questions if so:

- 1) Is this the right and desired way to solve this issue ? If so, why ?
- 2) When I remove both of the lines mentioned above (`void funcFromASrcFile(); 
  void funcFromBSrcFile();`) - I get the compilation error, Yet, When I leave ***only*** the first one (`void funcFromASrcFile();`), again, it compiles and runs fine. Why is that ?
- 3) Off course, if there is anything else fundamental I'm missing, please elaborate.

The code in each of the files are as follows:

***classA.h***

```
#pragma once

void funcFromASrcFile();

class A
{
    public:
    A();
    ~A();

    void FooA() const;
};
```

**classA.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "classA.h"

using namespace std;

void funcFromASrcFile()
{
    cout << "funcFromASrcFile" << endl;
}

A::A()
{
    cout << "A::A" << endl;
}

A::~A()
{
    cout << "A::~A" << endl;
}

void A::FooA() const
{
    cout << "A::Foo" << endl;
}
```

***classB.h***

```
#pragma once

void funcFromBSrcFile();

class B
{
    public:
    B();
    ~B();

    void FooB() const;
};
```

**classB.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "classB.h"

using namespace std;

void funcFromBSrcFile()
{
    cout << "funcFromBSrcFile" << endl;
}

B::B()
{
    cout << "B::B" << endl;
}

B::~B()
{
    cout << "B::~B" << endl;
}

void B::FooB() const
{
    cout << "B::Foo" << endl;
}
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "classA.h"
#include "classB.h"

void funcFromASrcFile();
void funcFromBSrcFile();

using namespace std;

int main(int , char**)
{
    cout << "main - start" << endl;
    cout << "main - creating an A object on the stack" << endl; 
    A a;
    a.FooA();
    funcFromASrcFile();

    cout << "main - creating an B object on the stack" << endl; 
    B b;
    b.FooB();
    funcFromBSrcFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Your help is much appreciated !!

Thanks,

Guy.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce on TIO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44008238#44008238).

Comment: I can't reproduce on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) or [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online) either. Probably something is wrong with your machine. Try updating your g++.

Comment: ([Relevant meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364314/should-we-close-vote-questions-that-we-cannot-reproduce-on-our-machines) if anyone want to read)

Comment: Compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -H -g`; have some header file *declaring* global names, and define `extern void funcFromASrcFile();` there (or put that in the incorrectly named `classA.h`)

Comment: BTW, look also into some small free software projects from [github](http://github.com/)